# Django FormView inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am new in python and django, please can someone explain me inheritance mechanizm in django/python class based views? Example is here:

```
class FormViewA(FormView):
    form_class = MyFormClass
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('my_url')
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        print "in FormViewA"
        return super(FormViewA, self).form_valid(form)


class FormViewB(FormViewA):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        print "in FormViewB"
        return super(FormViewB, self).form_valid(form)
```

If I use `FormViewB` to create a form in my templates the code from `form_valid` from `FormViewA` still run and I see this output:

```
in FormViewB
in FormViewA
```

Explain me please, what am I missing, why the code from overridden method still works here? Is it overridden like in the c++? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hm, yeah I see now from similar questions about `super`, will it work correct if I wll not call parent method? Anyways thank you very much for your answer, It helps.

Comment: If I inherit from `FormView`, I need to dublicate too many login from parent class,  I had hoped to avoid this, but it better  to make some "copypaste" here, right?

Comment: You are welcome. I compiled my comments into an answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling `super()` in `FormViewB`, which means the `form_valid` method of `FormViewA`. If you don't want to see `'in FormViewA'` you should either

1. Don't call `super()` at all: In this case, you must be sure that super does not include any crucial code you will require. Because when you skip calling `FormViewA.super()` you are not calling `FormView.super()` either.
2. Inherit directly from `FormView`. If you have common code in both `FormViewA` and `FormViewB`, you can extract this code to another method.